# Android programmatically created ImageView not showing

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'm trying to create an array of `ImageViews` programmatically. Here is my code (i and j are for counters)

```
imageViews = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(3*i+j != 8) {
                ImageView subImage = new ImageView(this);
                subImage.setImageBitmap(pieces.get(3 * i + j));
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
                subImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
                subImage.setX(i * 100f);
                subImage.setY(j * 100f);
                subImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViews.add(subImage);
            }
        }
    }
```

pieces is an arraylist of Bitmaps. Anyway, none of the image views are showing. I'm new to all this so I'm sure I'm doing all sorts of wrong.Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you displaying the imageViews?

Comment: you forgot addView into parent View `parent_View.addView(subImage)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add view in your layout object just like below.

`layout_object.addView(subImage);`
and finally you have to set which view you want to display like
`setContentView(layout_object);`

hope this answer is useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

YOu have to create **layout in xml file**

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

**and in java file**

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imageViews = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                if(3*i+j != 8) {
                    ImageView subImage = new ImageView(this);
                    subImage.setImageBitmap(pieces.get(3 * i + j));                        
                    subImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    subImage.setLayoutParams(params);
                    imageViews.add(subImage);

                    layout.addView(subImage);

                }
            }
        }
```

**NOTE** : *if you have more images which is not set on the screen then first creat Scrollview and in that put linear layout*

Answer (score 1):

you've created all the imageviews but you need a layout to display those images. lets say a LinearLayout, so first create a layout in your xml file,

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, add the images inside this layout.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
imageViews = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(3*i+j != 8) {
                ImageView subImage = new ImageView(this);
                subImage.setImageBitmap(pieces.get(3 * i + j));
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
                subImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
                subImage.setX(i * 100f);
                subImage.setY(j * 100f);
                subImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViews.add(subImage);

            }
        }
    }

for(int i=0; i< imageViews.size(); i++){ // iterating through the arraylist and adding the images to the linearlayout
    mylinearLayout.addView(imageViews.get(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you having the arraylist of imageview objects..
just iterate this array list and add to the main parent layout

suppose your main layout is RelativeLayout

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

save this object in java code

```
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
//now iterate the arraylist of imageviews
for(ImageView iv:imageViews)
{
    rl.addView(iv);
}
```